# Service killed after stopForeground(false)

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

How to reproduce:

- Open my app
- Bind service and call `startForeground(true)`

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
  bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  ```
- Remove my app from recent apps
- Click Notification's pause button (simple action)
- When pause is pressed my Service call `startForeground(false)` to keep notification but make it swipable.

It works for Android 6.0, but on 4.1.1 it restarts my Service:

```
D/MediaPlayerService: freeNotification...
I/ActivityManager: Killing 5163:org.test.app.debug/u0a50: remove task
W/AudioService:   AudioFocus   audio focus client died
I/AudioService:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus(): removing entry for android.media.AudioManager@5367ef4ccom.kometared.audiomaterialapp.audioservice.MediaPlayerService$2@536c2c24
W/AudioService:   RemoteControlClient died
W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service org.test.app.debug/com.kometared.audiomaterialapp.audioservice.MediaPlayerService in 5000ms
```

On Android 5.0/5.1 it follows to similar result, but Service even not restarting:

```
D/MediaPlayerService: freeNotification...
I/ActivityManager: Killing 2181:org.test.app.debug/u0a61 (adj 9): remove task
W/MediaFocusControl:   AudioFocus   audio focus client died
I/MediaFocusControl: AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for android.os.BinderProxy@1c6e92f6
W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10061/pid_2181/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service org.test.app.debug/com.kometared.audiomaterialapp.audioservice.MediaPlayerService in 1000ms
W/MediaSessionRecord: Removing dead callback in pushEvent.
                                                                android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                                    at android.media.session.ISessionControllerCallback$Stub$Proxy.onSessionDestroyed(ISessionControllerCallback.java:189)
                                                                    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord.pushSessionDestroyed(MediaSessionRecord.java:613)
                                                                    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord.access$3800(MediaSessionRecord.java:66)
                                                                    at com.android.server.media.MediaSessionRecord$MessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSessionRecord.java:1232)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:271)
                                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:172)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Is it a bug?** Or I do something wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `startService()` (or does your notification's action use `PendingIntent.getService()`?) and where do you call `stopSelf()`? It says your service crashed - are you swiping away your notification or the task from the Recents screen?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I bind service without calling `startService()`. I don't call `stopSelf()` in my service as I use `MediaStyle.setShowCancelButton(true)` to let user cancel notification on old android versions. Service crashed/stopped after I clicked to Notification's button that executes `MediaSessionCompat.Callback.onPause()`. If I remove `stopForeground(false)` from `Callback.onPause()` everything works okay, but I can't swipe my notification in this case.

Comment: How does your Notification's button execute `Callback.onPause()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Through magic of `mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);`, I guess.

Comment: That's not how notification buttons work. Notification actions trigger a `PendingIntent`. How do you construct that `PendingIntent`?

Comment: @Alexandr it may help if you post your Service's code, or at least the relevant parts of it, so that way we can see exactly what you're doing to start and stop the foreground service that is causing the issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake there is a full code of my Service, If it can help. http://pastebin.com/yjz7VeHq

Comment: MediaStyleHelper's sources: http://pastebin.com/XS1BbWgi

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yeah, action is added by                 `.addAction(MediaStyleHelper.newPlayPauseAction(this, isPlaying()))` It creates `Action` from `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Yeah, that calls through to your `MediaButtonReceiver`, which then calls `startService()` on your Service (hence why you get the `Intent` in `onStartCommand()`).

That doesn't explain why `freeNotification()` happens before the `remove task` line in your logcat. That clearly looks like you're hitting pause and then removing your app from recent apps.

Comment: When does your `onTaskRemoved` log appear in your logcat?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It doesn't appear at all on every version with this problem. (4.1.1 ~ 5.1)

Comment: @ianhanniballake sorry for the false information. Now `onTaskRemoved` happens when I swipe out my app from "recent apps". But it happens second time when `Service` restarted. I also notice that my `extends Application` class's `onCreate` called and rebind `Service` through it. There is short video that demonstrates my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfojMHgwpww